# Speaker not working to full potential while using Elementary OS like it did when i used Windows

Tags: release-juno, ubuntu

I recently switched from Windows to Elementary OS and i found that my speaker doesn't work like it did when i was using Windows. I don't think their is any hardware problem because it worked fine in Windows. Please Help.

Comment: Please specify what do you mean under "not working to full potential". General volume too low? Or some other parameters?

Comment: Even after keeping the volume at maximum level, i receive very low sound from the speaker which didn't happen on windows. I assume there's something wrong with elementary os or maybe the appropriate driver isn't installed.

Comment: Have you tried configuring your audio via `alsamixer` command in Terminal?

Comment: @a-tokarev i actually tried pavucontrol on terminal and it quite worked.